# SQL ignore condition clause if the value is null or empty

Tags: sql

I have the following query

```
SELECT id, namn, postA, postB postN FROM k.dbo.PF WHERE
        namn LIKE @name + '%' AND
        postA LIKE @address + '%' AND
        postB LIKE @coAddress + '%' AND
        postN LIKE @zip + '%' AND
        k.dbo.status = 0
```

This query works as long as I have the correct values in all the fields. But in this case, the care of address (postB column) can sometimes be null in the database. But when I provide the parameter @coAddress with a null value, the query doesn't return anything. How can I rewrite this query so that it will skip the **AND** clause completely if the coAddress parameter is null?

Comment: `(namn LIKE @name + '%' or @name is null) and ...`

Comment: There are straightforward answers to this, but this approach does come with performance implications. If you have the time, you may want to read [this](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html), which covers all the bases on dynamic search conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OR`:

```
SELECT id, namn, postA, postB postN
FROM k.dbo.PF
WHERE (@name is null OR namn LIKE @name + '%') AND
      (@address is null OR postA LIKE @address + '%') AND
      (@coAddress is null OR postB LIKE @coAddress + '%') AND
      (@zip is null OR postN LIKE @zip + '%') AND
      k.dbo.status = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

```
SELECT id, namn, postA, postB postN FROM k.dbo.PF WHERE
        namn LIKE @name + '%' AND
        postA LIKE @address + '%' AND
        (@coAddress is NULL or postB LIKE @coAddress + '%') AND
        postN LIKE @zip + '%' AND
        k.dbo.status = 0
```

Any expression involving a NULL value will always return false except for "IS NULL".